# Convert string to numbers with decimal places

Tags: javascript

I need value to return the full number to me: 249.87. But using `parseFloat ()` or `parseInt ()` always returns 249.

How can I get the full number back? Has as?

```js
string = '249.87' 
value = parseFloat (string) 
console.log (value) // Return number 249.
```

Comment: `parseFloat()` does not do what you say it does, as you can immediately verify in your browser console.

Comment: Can I convert this string to return me as the complete number I need? @Pointy

Comment: Yes, either `Number(yourString)` or `parseFloat(yourString)` will work.

Comment: That code works fine. You can see in the snippet that it returns `249.87` not `249` like you state

Comment: I tested on my developer console and it does what you need

string = '249.87' 
value = parseFloat (string) 
249.87
console.log (value) 
249.87

Comment: Sorry guys, in my representation I did it wrong ... Actually the string value = '249,87' ... That is, the problem is because the value of my string is a comma instead of a period